# Keyboard is dismissed automatically in iOS9.1 on App Switch

Tags: ios, keyboard, ios9.1

I have a screen with a `textField` in my app. Suppose the settings app is already present in the background with `keyboard` shown.

Now, I bring up the `keyboard` in my app and then switch to settings app; a glitch is visible. The `keyboard` flickers as if it hides and shows instantaneously.

Also, if I switch back to my app, the `keyboard` is gone. This issue exists only in `iOS9`. 
`iOS9.1` to be precise.

Is this a known issue?

Please provide your valuable suggestions or a solution for the same. 
Thanks.

Comment: have you try [self viewEndediting : NO]; ?

Comment: Hi @ChandraVaghasiya. I didn't quite get what you said. I don't want the keyboard to disappear when I move to another screen. It should be there when I come back, if that is what you meant.

Comment: yes..try it i think i will work.

Comment: i guess what you meant is `[self.view endEditing:NO]`. However, that doesn't fix the issue.